# Drawing a dendrogram from nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

i'm having a problem with drawing a dendrogram in python

i have the following data:

```py
[{
    "label": "11",
    "ro": 66.33,
    "content": [{
        "label": "10",
        "ro": 4.67,
        "content": [{
            "label": "8",
            "ro": 0.5,
            "content": [{"label": "4"},{"label": "5"}]
            },{
                "label": "3"
            }]
        },{
        "label": "9",
        "ro": 1.33,
        "content": [{
            "label": "7",
            "ro": 0.5,
            "content": [{"label": "1"},{"label": "2"}]
        },{
            "label": "6"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

this is the same data but printed as a tree:

```
        __11______
       /          \
    __9          __10
   /   \        /    \
  7     6      8      3
 / \          / \
1   2        4   5
```

i can't figure out how to draw the dendrogram bellow from this data set, i'm very confused.

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: scipy has a [`dendrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i can't figure out how to turn my nested dictd data into something that i can use in scipy ... i would also prefer to use matplotlib... i would still use scipy if i could understand how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data representation to linkage matrix :

```
[
    [2,  1,  0.5,   0], 
    [5,  4,  0.5,   0], 
    [6,  7,  1.33,  0], 
    [3,  8,  4.66,  0], 
    [9,  10,  66.33, 0]
]
```

Then, i used the [dendrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) scipy function recommended by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) to draw it :

```
def draw(linkage_matrix):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    dn = dendrogram(linkage_matrix)
    plt.show()
```

This is the result :

[image]

This was a [hierarchical clustering solution](https://github.com/logxseven/Hierarchical-Clustering/).